# I get TaskCanceledException in mscorlib.dll when I try getUpdates method with default values in Telegram bot api in c#

Tags: c#, task, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to write a program to communicate with a telegram bot, and I'm using C# api:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Telegram.Bot;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run().Wait();
        }
        static async Task Run()
        {
            var bot = new Telegram.Bot.Api("bot<token>");
            var offset = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                var updates = await bot.GetUpdates(offset);
                foreach (var update in updates)
                {
                    await bot.SendTextMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, update.Message.Text);
                    offset = update.Id + 1;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

the problem is that I get aggregate exception when I try to use the default GetUpdates() method defined in the api. and this is the error stack:

```
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Telegram.Bot.Api.<SendWebRequest>d__78`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at ConsoleApplication2.Program.<Run>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Sasan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 24
```

I understand that when I try to request for Updates using Long Polling:

```
var updates = await bot.GetUpdates(offset,100,500);
```

the problem seems to go away, but that doesn't seem right.
if anyone has any information that could help me, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: What's the `InnerException`?

Comment: i don't exactly know. i wrote in the error stack, if you could help me find innter exception.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc80ssc(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: inner exception is null

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete example so we can observe the error you're seeing.

Comment: Look, the exact code i'm running is included in original message. The only thing is I use telegram bot using NuGet. Yesterday I updated the package and now the problem is solved. Thank u.